# ClassLoader getResource() in called jar uses resources from the caller

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have two java projects. Project B is a utility, meant to be packaged as a jar and called by other projects. Project A needs to call project B. However, when project B calls ClassLoader getResource(), it is loading resources from project A. How do I get it to load from project B?
It seems like this should be easy, so I feel that I must be missing something simple.
The following code is in the project B, called from project A. path/to/file.txt is in the resources folder in project B.

```
System.out.println(Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("path/to/file.txt").toURI()).toString());

Output: C:\Users\....\projectA\target\test-classes
```

Comment: `getResource(...)` will return an URL like `jar:/path/to/B.jar!/path/to/file.txt`which Path is actually not able to use as this is a file contained in a file. Try to use `File` instead of `Path`. The output should be somethin like `file:/path/to/B.jar!/path/to/file.txt` instead. Also, do not use relative paths for resource loading. Change `path/to/file.txt` to `/path/to/file.txt`. Also consider `getResourceAsStream(...)` if you want to load the bytes from that file directly instead of `getResource(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Normally the way you achieve this is to include `path/to/file.txt` as a resource in `B.jar`.

As an example, include `Guava` 19.0 as a compile time dependency in your Maven project (it looks like you're using Maven).  The following code works for me:

```
// pom.properties is bundled in guava-19.0.jar.
URL resource = Example.class.getResource("/META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties");
System.out.println(resource.toString());
```